# Restrict AD user to computer where DNS name is more than 15 chars?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to restrict a AD user to one computer.
You can add it with `Account` > `Log On To` > `Computer name`.

Now I see you can only add a computer name that is not longer than 15 chars.

How can I solve it, because my DNS name is like CA-MANAGEMENT-001.internal.domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in this image, you can type the NetBIOS name of the computer.

If the DNS name is longer than 15 chars, the NetBIOS name is usually the first 15 chars. You can check this *on the computer*, under `System` - `Change` (Computer Name/Domain) - `More`.

[image: Logon Workstations dialog box, with NetBIOS marked]

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the help, but the problem didn't seem to be the name but an RDP issue. Thanks for the visualisation and fast respons.